# Portal 2 crashes on startup in Windows 8.1 preview

Tags: portal-2, windows-8.1

Ever since I got Windows 8.1 preview, Portal 2 seems to crash after 5 seconds when I launch it. I could launch it fine when I had Windows 8! Has anyone got it to work on Windows 8.1? If so how?

Comment: I've removed the last question about downgrading from the preview as it's not on-topic for this site, but according to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq - "Uninstalling the preview isn't supported. However, it may be possible to restore your entire system to its factory condition."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Various answers [here](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864971765439144503/) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-gaming/unable-to-play-portal-1-2-after-windows-81/58ff5acd-fef2-4031-a586-d0a248c3c339) indicate that uninstalling and reinstalling the game will fix the problem *(none of them mentioned if they tried [verifying the game cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335) first, which should theoretically do the same thing, but be much faster)*.

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08a3a358-4bc0-4ac3-a15d-f035245aac36/windows-81-preview-causes-games-to-stop-working) post also suggests that you may need special graphics-card drivers for Windows 8.1, which you should be able to obtain through Windows Update, or *(failing that)* from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: I can confirm through testing with the final release of Windows 8.1 that this issue still occurs if you've upgraded from a previous version of Windows 8. Windows 8.1 automatically upgraded the graphics drivers as part of the upgrade process, verifying the game cache *did* resolve the problem without a reinstall.